# What is the ammount of current when using no resistors

Tags: current, resistors

Ohm's law states that V=IR, thus if we have a 9V battery and one would use no resistance (R=0) then I= 9/0 which can't be done.

Then what happens to the current? Does this mean there is an infinite amount of current? Or does a battery have a max amount of current it can provide (if so, what is this max amount of current)?

Or do wires have a little resistance for example: R = 1 * 10^-6. This leads to an insane amount of current.

Comment: Simpler than that : the battery itself and the wire both have resistance.

Comment: Doesn't this question pop up every month or so? Are they all closed and deleted somehow? Can't find them now.

Comment: @pipe Yes and no, that question looks at the voltage while I'm interested in the current. But the accepted answer, does talk about resistance

Comment: I'd say its the single most common confusion when learning electrical engineering.  We teach the subject in a way that opens up this sort of question and they don't like to answer it until much later, when you have enough EE under your belt to be unafraid of imperfect voltage sources.  Opening the circuit on an inductor without a resistor is probably the second most common of these.  You'll come across the same issue there soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory if it was an ideal power supply without internal resistance, and wires would not have resistance, you would have infinite current flowing, which is actually not possible as there is no resistance so there would also be no voltage drop so it's a very undefined situation.

However, if you look at V=I*R from another angle, having zero resistance means that there is no voltage drop anywhere, regardless of what the current is, which might make more sense.

In practice, wires have resistance, but the battery has even larger internal resistance due to it's chemistry and structure. It is not likely to get more than few hundred milliamperes of short circuit current out of a 9V battery.

OK, I was wrong, I shorted a 9V battery with a multimeter in 10A range, and got a short circuit current of approximately 2.5A. The open circuit voltage of the battey was 9.15V.

Comment: No resistance implying no voltage drop is only true for finite currents; once you get infinities into the mix things stop working so easily.

Answer (score 4):

The 9v battery has internal resistance (see datasheet), so R is not actually equal to zero. If you short out a very large power supply (R<<1) you get a lot of current, but R never actually reaches zero, so you can plug it into that formula and get the short circuit current.

Answer (score 0):

I think the theoretical answer would be an infinite amount of current. A more practical approach would be to do a simple experiment using different resistances and noting down the different current values. Then you can extrapolate that result to a very small resistance value to see how the current behaves. Might be interesting to check out the actual result.

Comment: "Might be interesting to check out the actual result." That depends how you define "interesting". If you try to check this out with a car battery for example, you will probably have a fire or an explosion to deal with. Not to mention the burns you got if you tried to disconnect the short circuit with your hands. In other words, *don't try this at home!*

Comment: As the question asked concerns real circuits it will be useful to see how it works. Do not interpret "interesting" as explosive though. Keep the useful point raised by @alephzero in mind. Use small voltage battery not a car battery.